# skip to next item in dictionary

Tags: python

I have nested for loops, i think this is making things complicated here. 
Here is the dict i have

```
dict1 = {'1': '##', '2': '##'}
```

I am looping through this dict and here is the code

```
for key,value in dict1.items():
    ###some code ###
        if ##condition is true move to next key in the for loop which is '2'##
           dict1.next()
```

I have used dict1.next(). But this is throwing an error "dict' object has no attribute 'next'"

Even tried dict1[key] += 1 and dict1[key] = dict1.setdefault(key, 0) + 1

I understand when skipping to next key in dictionary we have to refer index of key to move on to next item. But no luck with anything and I m not sure using "continue" would fulfil my purpose, because currently I have only one value for each corresponding key ("continue" works if it so), but I want to use this code even if each key had more than one value respectively. Such that "If" condition is true for key 1 and its first corresponding value, the next iteration should be for key 2 and its values respectively.

Sorry for long story

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: The loop itself will move to the next element as a result of the enclosing for loop. All you need to do is ignore any values you don't want.

Answer (score 3):

what's wrong with using continue?

```
dict1 = {'1': [1,4,7], '2': '##'}

for key in dict1.keys():
    if key == "1":
        continue
    else:
        print key, dict1[key]

>>> '2 ##'
```

You can have the nexy key with the following:

```
keys = dict1.keys()
n = len(keys)
for i in range(n):
    thisKey = keys[i]
    if some_condition():
        nextKey = keys[(i + 1) % n]
        nextValue = dict1[nextKey]
        print thisKey, nextValue
```

You have a list of keys, you iterate over the length of the keys.
If your condition is true, you can extract the next key and value.

Comment: Hi omri. As I said I m not sure if "continue" works to skip to next key (which is '2' in my example) when the "if" condition for key '1' is satisfied, considering the situation when I have more than one value for each key.

Comment: Each key has one value.. the value can be object, list, dict basically everything. if you jump over the key, you jump over his value as well. @KrishnaChaitanya

Comment: Yeah jumping over its value is also fine with me. Just if the condition is true for that key '1' and any of its value, just have to move on to key '2'

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya added another snippet that might help you

Comment: thanks for sharing that snippet..just a question your snippet "keys = dict1.keys()" . Is keys a list here?

Comment: in py2 `dict.keys()` returns a list, in py3 it returns an iterator called a "view". https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views